# How do I get a light blue color in Xcode for a Navigation Bar Tint Color?

Tags: ios, swift

I am changing the Navigation Bar color in my app (barTintColor). My app's "color theme" is light blue.

I specifically am using:

```
    var color = UIColor.redColor()
```

Specifically, **what do I replace the *redColor* with**, to get a light blue color.

Comment: Did you even *look* at the documentation for UIColor?

Comment: Yes. There is nothing listed for a UI color.

Comment: I assure you, there is [complete documentation for UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/).

Answer (score 1):

UIColor has the following initializer:

```
init(red red: CGFloat, green green: CGFloat, blue blue: CGFloat, alpha alpha: CGFloat)
```

Here you insert the values from 0 to 1 for every parameter. Just go to any colorpicker out there and get the values.

If you want to convert 0...255 to 0...1 just do value/255

Comment: Though it's frustrating when question askers do not show meaningful research effort, we must do our best to remain civil with one another.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Hi Fallow this to change color :

// You just define this line in header file

#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue)            [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

//And change the color like below given code :

textLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x0D78C8)

// You can give the GRB color value here simple
```